# java.lang.NullPointerException at unknown source

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I get a **weird error** on my Android app. I couldn't found any useful source about this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.uusoftware.burclar.a.a$1$1.onClick(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.d$a$3.onItemClick(Unknown Source)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1509)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3467)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4830)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I couldn't detect where gives this error neither which code block gives this error in the app. Thanks.

Addition: Here is the my project on Github: https://github.com/aykutuludag/GunlukBurclar

Addition 2: Here is my app on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.uusoftware.burclar

Addition 3: I suspect app crashes on these code block but I don't know why it crashes:

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        final int position = holder.getPosition();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.chooseaction);
        builder.setItems(R.array.choose_actions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Get Uri
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/GÃ¼nlÃ¼k BurÃ§lar";
                File f = new File(path);
                File file[] = f.listFiles();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                if (which == 0) {
                    // Show
                    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file[position]), "image/*");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } else if (which == 1) {
                    // Share
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file[position]));
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    // Delete
                    file[position].delete();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.deleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    intent = new Intent(mContext, FavoritesActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    ((FavoritesActivity) mContext).finish();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
};
```

Comment: add java code, to see where is the error.

Comment: @khelwood I don't think this is a duplicate of that source. Because there is no line 'org.uusoftware.burclar.a.a$1$1.onClick' in my app. This is not a regular null point exception.

Comment: @W4R10CK I couldn't detect where to error occurs.

Comment: enter java code so we can see.

Comment: post your java code

Comment: It is a third-party code. He does not have access to the source. How can he post a source code here in that case?

Comment: Share git repository of this library

Comment: You should use third-party libraries with debug information included if you want to see source of error.

Comment: I added my project to Github: https://github.com/aykutuludag/GunlukBurclar

Comment: org.uusoftware.burclar is a horoscope application. So if it's not yours then you probably have a connection to an ad network that failed for some reason. If not then you have a class in your application where it fails in a onClick function. You can see this errors with source maps.

Comment: @DanielPersson no Daniel it is my app. I added project to Github.

Comment: These classes have onCLick.

https://github.com/aykutuludag/GunlukBurclar/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onClick

Comment: @DanielPersson it is true but I couldn't detect which one of them gives the error.

Comment: I believe I found the error. When open FavoritesActivity (https://github.com/aykutuludag/GunlukBurclar/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/uusoftware/burclar/FavoritesActivity.java) and try to share or delete or see favorites app crashes but I don't know why it crashes.

Comment: @W4R10CK: please don't edit titles to include [solved], we don't do that here. The acceptance system is enough.

Comment: @halfer: Thanks for suggestion, will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

I found error finally. Unfortunately reason of crash is Turkish characters.

**Wrong**

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/GÃ¼nlÃ¼k BurÃ§lar";
```

**True**

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Günlük Burçlar";
```

Comment: I had the same problem a couple of days ago.